# Multiple Textbox Fields using JQuery, Ajax, PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm done with the codes and its working.

```
 <form name="registration" id="registration" action="" method="post">
    <div id="reg_names">
       <div class="control-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="prefix[]" id="prefix">
                    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                    <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="fullname[]" id="fullname" />                   
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="control-group">
            <label">Position</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="position[]" id="position" />                               
            </div>
       </div>
    </div> <!-- end of reg_names -->

    <div id="reg_names_ext"></div>

    <div class="add_delegate">
        <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add">Add a delegate</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <a class="submit" id="register" href="javascript:void(0)">SUBMIT</a>
        </div>
    </div>    

 </form>
```

The codes in ADD A DELEGATE button as shown below:

```
var Registration = {

  removeElement: function(element){
     $('#' + element).remove();
  }

}

$(document).ready(function(){       

    var i = 1;
    $('.add').click(function(){
        $( "#reg_names" ).clone().appendTo( "#reg_names_ext" );
        $('#reg_names_ext').find('#reg_names').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', 'reg_names' + i).find('input').val('');
            $('#reg_names' + i).prepend('<hr>');
            $('#reg_names' + i).append('<a href="javascript:Registration.removeElement(\'reg_names' + i + '\')" id="remove">Remove</a>');
        });
    i++;
    });

});
```

Here's my code for submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#register').click(function(){

     var dataString = {};

     var prefix = $('select[name="prefix[]"]').map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
     var fullname = $('input[name="fullname[]"]').map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
     var position = $('input[name="position[]"]').map(function(){ return this.value }).get();

     for(var i=0; i < fullname.length; i++)
    { 
        dataString[i] = {
            'prefix'    : prefix[i],
            'fullname'  : fullname[i],
            'position'  : position[i]
        }
    }   

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "insert.php",
         dataType: "json",
         data: { "data" : JSON.stringify(dataString) },
         success: function(data){   
              if(data==true){
                  $('#registration')[0].reset();
                  alert("Congratulations!");
              }else{
                  $('#registration')[0].reset();
                  alert("The system found an error");   
              }                             
         }          
    });

  });

});
```

Here's my connection.php code:

```
<?php

function connect($sql){

  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "admin";
  $password = "";
  $db_name = "sample";

  $db = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to server.');
  mysql_select_db($db_name, $db) or die('Database does not exist.');
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$db);
  return $result;
}

?>
```

Here's my insert.php code

```
<?php

//Start session
session_start();

//database connection
require_once 'connection.php';

$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    $prefix    = strtoupper($data[$key]['prefix']);
    $fullname  = strtoupper($data[$key]['fullname']);
    $position  = strtoupper($data[$key]['position']);

    $values[]  = "('$prefix','$fullname','$position')";
}

$query_values = implode(',', $values);

$result = connect( "INSERT INTO `data` (prefix, fullname, position) VALUES $query_values " );

if($result){
   echo json_encode(true);
}else{
   echo json_encode(false);
}

?>
```

I WISH IT WILL HELP FOR FUTURE PROGRAMMERS.. HEHEHE :)
I'M HAPPY TO HELP..

Comment: Check in your database whether the data is insered or not and check in console for any errors. Also, don't copy-paste your full code here, specify the block of code where you stuck.

Comment: Please check your console for any error

Comment: @MichaelQuitorio Kindly post the error being outputted for more clearer analogy of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what appeared in firebug when I submit what I have entered in the textbox:

```
cfm_prefix=[object Object]&cfm_fullname=[object Object]&cfm_position=[object Object]
```

Comment: its because the value of the data your trying to get is an object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your error is in this part of your code.

```
 var cfm_prefix = $('input[name^=prefix]');
 var cfm_fullname = $('input[name^=fullname]');
 var cfm_position = $('input[name^=position]');
```

Make sure you're getting the value of the textbox. Try this code:

```
 var cfm_prefix = $('input[name^=prefix]').val();
 var cfm_fullname = $('input[name^=fullname]').val();
 var cfm_position = $('input[name^=position]').val();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @michael. I'm just wondering you set your dataString on your ajax call like this: 

var dataString = "cfm_prefix="+cfm_prefix+"&cfm_fullname="+cfm_fullname+"&cfm_position="+cfm_position; but in insert.php you use post as $_POST['cfm_prefix'] etc

Answer (score 0):

**Few of the things ive seen**

This one should be in Json form

```
var dataString = "cfm_prefix="+cfm_prefix+"&cfm_fullname="+cfm_fullname+"&cfm_position="+cfm_position;
```

So change into format like this

```
 var dataString ={
                'prefix' : cfm_prefix,
                'cfm_fullname': cfm_fullname
                };
```

Second thing is your data gets values in a form of object

```
     var cfm_prefix = $('input[name^=prefix]');
     var cfm_fullname = $('input[name^=fullname]');
     var cfm_position = $('input[name^=position]');
```

just rephrase to this code to simplify

```
     var cfm_prefix = $('#prefix').val();
     var cfm_fullname = $('#fullname').val();
     var cfm_position = $('#position').val();
```

Comment: in that case just try to debug by echoing in each line from the connection to insert method